# jtable's validation engine not working Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, jtable, twig

iam working with a site that using PHP+jTable+twig template. When i add some validation with validationengine it got me an error by using chrome's developer tool

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function"
>
> "Uncaught TypeError: form.find(...).not(...).die is not a function"

i follow all the instruction on http://www.jtable.org/Demo/UsingWithValidationEngine2

im already include Javascript and CSS files for validation engine

```
{% block template_libs_js %}
{{ parent() }}
        <script src="{{ theme_path }}plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ mdasset_path_js }}jquery.jtable.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ mdasset_path_js }}jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ mdasset_path_js }}jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

for CSS

```
{% block head %}
{{ parent() }}
    <meta name="description" content="Halaman Master Data yang hanya dapat diakses oleh administrator">
    
    <link href="{{ core_asset_path_css }}jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{ mdasset_path }}themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{ mdasset_path_css }}validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
{% endblock %}
```

here is my main code

```
{% block template_js_jquery %}
{{ parent() }}
        //Prepare jTable
        $('#cntRefAsisten').jtable({
            title: 'Ref. Asisten',
            paging: true,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'nama_asisten ASC',
            selecting: true, //Enable selecting
            multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
            selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
            //selectOnRowClick: false, //Enable this to only select using checkboxes
            actions: {
                listAction: '{{ site_url() }}masterdata/ref_asisten/fetch',
                createAction: '{{ site_url() }}masterdata/ref_asisten/add',
                updateAction: '{{ site_url() }}masterdata/ref_asisten/save',
                deleteAction: '{{ site_url() }}masterdata/ref_asisten/del'
            },
            fields: {
                id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                nama_asisten: {
                    title: 'Nama Asisten',
                    width: '30%',
                    inputClass: 'validate[required]'
                },
                keterangan: {
                    title: 'Keterangan',
                    type: 'textarea',
                    width: '20%'
                }
            },
            //Initialize validation logic when a form is created
            formCreated: function (event, data) {
                data.form.validationEngine();
            },
            //Validate form when it is being submitted
            formSubmitting: function (event, data) {
                return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
            },
            //Dispose validation logic when form is closed
            formClosed: function (event, data) {
                data.form.validationEngine('hide');
                data.form.validationEngine('detach');
            }
        });

        //Load list from server
        $('#cntRefAsisten').jtable('load');
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `jQueery.live` was removed in jQueery version 1.9 - which version of jQueery are you using?

Comment: im using "jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"...thankyou  for your attention im really apreciate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.live()` is deprecated and has been since jQuery 1.7. You should use `.on()`instead.

```
$("#a").live("click)......
```

Should be changed to

```
$("document").on("click","#a",function() {
    ....
});
```

Comment: thankyou sir...you help my world... there is a line in jqueryvalidationengine.js that should we change to "on" not "live" as you said sir....but now i got  an error "Uncaught TypeError: form.find(...).not(...).die is not a function" what should i do sir?